# javascript dynamic append variable for instant usage

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

wondering how to go with this case

how to properly assign the dynamic to combined into main_slider_{HEREneedtodynamic}

it will change need to properly assign at 3 places inside the for loop.

```
    var main_slider_ALL, main_slider_JHR, main_slider_BYG, main_slider_SLO;

        var xxx = new Array('ALL','JHR','BYG','SLO');

        for(let q = 0; q < xxx.length; q++){
                console.log( xxx[q] );

                main_slider_ALL = jQuery('.my_slider.'+xxx[q]).bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                pause: 5000,
                pagerSelector: '#pager-'+xxx[q],
                onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                    var lastSlideIndex = main_slider_ALL.getSlideCount() -1;
                    if(newIndex == lastSlideIndex){
                        main_slider_ALL.stopAuto();
                    }
                }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically build a variable name in the way you are attempting.  But you *can* dynamically reference an object property.

Combine your variables into an object:

```
var main_slider = {
  ALL: {}, JHR: {}, BYG: {}, SLO: {}
};
```

Then you can reference each property with your variables:

```
main_slider[xxx[q]] = jQuery('.my_slider.'+xxx[q]).bxSlider({
  //...
});
```

In fact, pretty much *any time* you find yourself creating multiple variables which follow a pattern and which need to be kept in sync in some way, what you're describing is either an array or an object.

---

Taking it a step further, with this you don't need your array literal, which just repeats information already found in the object.  You can infer the property names directly from the object:

```js
var main_slider = {
  ALL: {}, JHR: {}, BYG: {}, SLO: {}
};

for(var key of Object.keys(main_slider)) {
  console.log(key);
  // so in this loop "key" equals what "xxx[q]" is in your code
}
```